# How to setup EKRecurrenceRule rule for repeating once a week

Tags: ios, swift, eventkit

How can I best create a `EKRecurrenceRule` in swift to allow for scheduling an event once a week, possibly several days a week.

For example, a new event is to occur every Friday and Saturday weekly.

```
    var dayOfWeek = [EKWeekday.Friday, EKWeekday.Saturday]

    EKRecurrenceRule(recurrenceWithFrequency: EKRecurrenceFrequency.Weekly, interval: 1, daysOfTheWeek: dayOfWeek)
```

At present, above does not work

How can this be formulated?

*(The examples and tutorials for swift are sparse)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it:

```
let friday = EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek(.Friday)
let saturday = EKRecurrenceDayOfWeek(.Saturday)

EKRecurrenceRule(recurrenceWithFrequency: .Weekly, interval: 1, daysOfTheWeek: [friday, saturday], daysOfTheMonth: nil, monthsOfTheYear: nil, weeksOfTheYear: nil, daysOfTheYear: nil, setPositions: nil, end: nil)
```

Comment: I was overthinking the implementation.

Comment: Do you also know how to create an alert for the eventKit event? ie. 15 min before the event, the alert appears...

Comment: You can create an EKAlarm with a Negative offset value of NSTimeInterval and add this alarm to the event. `EKAlarm(relativeOffset: NSTimeInterval(-15000))`

Comment: Do you know how to setup a time picker for selecting such an interval?

Comment: You can use a UIPickerView.

Comment: Are you familiar with setting up to observe external changes in the calendar database in swift? : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ObservingChanges/ObservingChanges.html